# Java UUID string representation natural ordering

Tags: java, string, comparison, uuid

Say I have two UUID instances:

```
uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
uuid2 = UUID.randomUUID();
```

If those two compare such that `uuid1` is less than `uuid2` i.e.,

```
uuid1.compareTo(uuid2) // -1
```

is it always true that their string representations will compare to give the same result, i.e.,

```
uuid1.toString().compareTo(uuid2.toString()) // -1 ????
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, no. Here's a quick counter-example of two UUIDs for which the assertion does not hold:

- b230f7ab-9420-4a3e-a684-284c609e76a5
- 76d1f3c9-fc72-4f1a-ab48-28a858d760c5

Using the compareTo from UUID you get **-1**, while compareTo from the String results in **43**.

Comment: +1; from reading the API and the RFC, I would have expected consistent behaviour, though...

Comment: See http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7025832; Oracle will not fix the implementation and will probably not even admit that the Javadoc is wrong.